# Link specific button with specific modal

Tags: javascript

I need to propagate different content within a modal on a click of a button. My problem is—calling out the `div` element within JavaScript. As of right now, it's an ID and I can't have multiple ID's. I am very confused by everything since I am new to JS.

The simplest form, I just need **button 1** to link with **button 1**, **button 2** with **button 2**, and so on. I'm not sure what to change in my JS for this to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbLj68ua/10/

```
<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>
<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 3</button>

<!-- Content 1 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>1 Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>please link with 1</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><h3>Modal Footer</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Content 2 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>2 Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>please link with 2</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><h3>Modal Footer</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Content 3 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>3 Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>please link with 3</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><h3>Modal Footer</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks the buttons open the modal
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  };
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate between them using the index  `document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[i]`

Try it now:

```js
// Get the modal
    
    var modal = document.getElementById('detailmodal');


    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modalbutton");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    // When the user clicks the buttons open the modal 
    for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
      btn[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[i].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
 for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    for (let i = 0; i < window.length; i++) {
    window[i].onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    max-width: 850px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.8s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {right:-100px; opacity:0} 
  to {right:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {right:-100px; opacity:0}
  to {right:0; opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>

<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>

<button id="modalbutton" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 3</button>

<!-- Content 1 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>1 Modal Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>please link with 1</p>
    <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Content 2 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>2 Modal Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>please link with 2</p>
    <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Content 3 -->
<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>3 Modal Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>please link with 3</p>
    <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! This seems to work, however, I'm using "modalbutton" as an ID multiple times which is causing errors. And for some reason your change broke the close button haha

Comment: Your code was only considered index [0] and I already modified it. Good luck.

Comment: You're simply the best. Worked great in my site :D

Comment: Follow up pup, any clue why the click (out of the modal) no longer closes the modal? And any clue how to lock the background while the modal is open?

Comment: You just need to define the `<span class="close">`  before  the `<div id="detailmodal" class="modal">` and close it at the end  of the content and for pervented from scrolling add to css   `span  body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you don't want to have multiple id's. What you can do is set each button to a different id (modalbutton1, modalbutton2, etc.) Then in javascript get a reference to each button:

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById('modalbutton1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('modalbutton2');
```

Then for each button reference you'll attach an onclick handler

```
modal1.onclick=function(){ //Write your style code here }
modal2.onclick=function(){ //Write your style code here }
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I'm not exactly sure how to make this work correctly, but I think this is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

If your html content is static and modal's data isn't dynamic the safe way you can do this is with multiple IDs.I think it's not a good idea to use same id for multiple buttons and div tags.
if the modals div tags wouldn't in the specific order, buttons don't work properly and perhaps it shows the wrong modal.

so it's better to write like this:

```
        btns = document.querySelectorAll('[id*=modalbutton-]');

for (let i = 1; i <= btns.length; i++) {
    var modalClassName = 'detailmodal-';

    btn = document.getElementById('modalbutton-' + i);     
  closeBtn = document.querySelector('#' + modalClassName + i + ' .close');

  closeBtn.onclick = function() {
    modal = document.getElementById(modalClassName + i);
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }

  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal = document.getElementById(modalClassName + i);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

and html pattern for buttons and modals:

```
<button id="modalbutton-1" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<div id="detailmodal-1" class="modal">

<button id="modalbutton-2" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 2</button>
<div id="detailmodal-2" class="modal">
```

If you cant use multiple ids just use data attribute with some value. you can change code above to use attribute and it's value to show a right modal.

```
<button id="modalbutton" data-button-id="1" class="modalbutton">Open Modal 1</button>
<div id="detailmodal" data-modal-id="1" class="modal">
```

and change your for loop like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(event) {
    var btnId = event.target.getAttribute("data-button-id");
    var modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal-id='" + btnId +"']");
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I could get that script to run properly, but I definitely think this is the way I should go. http://jsfiddle.net/7he6jar0/